# Target in <button/> .xml

Tags: android, html, xml

we are adding a new tab and i m following the existing code and editing it. I got struck at this point this is from where the target page is called. can some one explain me how this line of code works.

```
<Button ID="btn"  X="198" Y="0" W="88" H="36"
        **Target="@invoke(/_view/0/90/80,Select,field);"**
        Style="Button"
        Type="Image"
        Enabled="1"
    >Newfield
```

this is done in .xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <button/>
```

tag submits the page. Can u give more detail about the problem

Comment: m adding a new tab to the existing page which already has some old tabs. To do this i m following the existing code field is the place where it gets content. I want to know what target does and what @invoke is mentioned for?